# Javascript website preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can i do a website preview on a link similar to facebook when you post a link?  with image and short description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had a go at this about a month ago and there are a couple of sites that you can post a url to and it'll create an image that you can link to.  though it takes time so it's not useful.

we then created a small tooltip with an iframe and put the site within the iframe.  you can tell the frame to size the contents so the effect was that you got a small version of the site.

the obvious problem, that we didn't see immediately, was that the tooltip contents were clickable.  :)  But if you clear the tooltip as you move off the link then the user should not be able to get to it.