# a website preview - loading a webpage using javascript Or Server-side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to show website preview on a link similar to facebook when a user post a link. my question has been repeated in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673913/javascript-website-preview) ,but I am going to ask specific information throughout my solutions. I have 2 solutions for showing webpage preview which are as follows:1. server side html process 2. client side html process.
**1. server-side html process** 
I used `System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url)` to retrieve the web page data in server side , and I tried to extract the most important information in the page ,but in most cases, main part of the page loads using javascript , therefore I do not have access to that information.
Another solution in server-side html process is to work with webBrowser and WebDocument objects. because I didn't work with these libraries and I don't know how much the Web server performance affect by applying this objects , I only present this solution for discussion .Therefore are there any server-side html graber which fetch all html data including javascript loaded html source?

**2. Client Side Html process** 
The simplest approach for client side is to use the iframe tag, but it has two following problems:

- a. I can not access to innerHTML of the frame for the links on other domains.
- b. I can not load https webpages  such as drop-box and facebook in the iframe
           because of "x-frame options" error.

My question is that, is there any other client-side solution to retrieve dynamic html  source(loaded by javascript) from 3rd party webpages (usually https)? Or can I solve above problems with some tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess server side approach would be most viable option. On client side you can use proxy services which allow to solve cross domain limitation, for example, [crossorigin](http://crossorigin.me/).

To generate a preview, similar to one Facebook provides, you need to get [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) information for target page. Libraries to process open graph data available for multiple platforms. [OpenGraph-Net](https://github.com/ghorsey/OpenGraph-Net) could be used on .NET plarform.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will consider your response, and get my result back to you.

Comment: OpenGraph-Net is the best answer to my problem. Thanks again.